# Logically ANDing two tracks together

Tags: mixing, audacity, spectrum

I have two audio tracks, X and Y, which are similar, but both have things added to them.

I want to take X and Y, and produce a new track Z with only the lower value of every frequency of each track at each time. In other words, I want to logically AND the spectra of X and Y.

This question is different from [Conditional math (intersection) to join two audio tracks](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/42647/) because while that one was trying to do vocal isolation with linear operations, here I'm trying to perform a generalized boolean operation on two tracks. (Adding two tracks together is almost an OR, and subtracting them is almost and OR NOT)

I would prefer to do this in Audacity, but if it is impossible in Audacity, and possible in other programs, I may switch if I have to.

Comment: Have you tried first adding a low pass filter(LPF) to get only low frequencies from both tracks? Otherwise I don’t see the difference between your question and the other. Seems like both are trying to isolate the similarities between two files.

Comment: @Timinycricket Apologies. The question was worded incorrectly.

Comment: Is your question actually "how do I do vocal isolation"? as opposed to "how do I do {insert method here} with my audio?" The reason I ask is that your {insert thing here} isn't what you need to do to achieve any form of vocal isolation. If your question _is_ actually to do with vocal isolation, it might be better suited to the DSP stack exchange where a lot of signal processing applications and methods get discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you do that requires math-type operations relies on the inputs being sample-aligned. Just consider that logical operations are bitwise operations - so what is it you are proposing? converting each sample to it's binary equivalent and then operating the boolean logic on the binary sample value? I am not sure this is going to get you where you need to be.

Time-sequential data such as this doesn't really fit well with these types of operations. You should be looking primarily at convolution and correlation operations which are DSP-related operations that leverage the power of the DFT/FFT operation in order to achieve fast processing.

Comment: I figured part of the process would be a FT across the sample, then to take the lower magnitude frequency for every frequency at every time point. I just didn't know how to do that, and wanted to avoid an XY question.

Comment: You need to be looking at either Matlab or Octave for this - take buffers, window them, do overlap-add  with the correct window for your overlap size then process the FFT of the windowed buffer.